# Increment integer field dynamically - Django

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

So I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=20000)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Where Vote is the attribute that I want to increment by one on every click.

The following Views:

```
import json
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from urllib.request import urlopen
from .models import Person
from .serializers import PersonSerializer
from django.views.generic import ListView

class PersonApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        persons = Person.objects.all()
        serializer = PersonSerializer(persons, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class PersonView(ListView):
    data = urlopen("<URL contatining JSON>").read()
    json_persons = json.loads(data)
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    for person in json_persons:
        if person['id'] not in [i.id for i in persons]:
            Person.objects.create(id=person['id'],
                                  name=person['name'],
                                  image_url=person['image_url'],
                                  title=person['title'],
                                  bio=person['bio'])
    model = Person
    context_object_name = 'persons'
```

In the views, I'm doing 2 things:

1. Show in my /api/ URL all my objects after being serialized.
2. Create objects using an external JSON URL

This what I have in my html:

```
{% for person in persons %}
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-controller="mainController">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <img ng-src="{{person.image_url}}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                        <h2>{{ person.name }}</h2>
                        <h3>{{ person.title }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ person.bio }}</p>
                        <form method="POST">
                            <h4>Want to work with {{ person.name }}? <img src="{% static "svg/thumbs-up.svg" %}"><input type="submit" value="Yes!"></h4>
                        </form>
                        <h5><b>{{ person.vote }}</b> people have said Yes!</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is where I show all the information.

Problem:

What I'm trying to do is be able to click on `<input>` tag with a value of 'Yes!', and have the `{{person.vote}}` increment by one. Of course, I would like to save this on the data base.

How can I accomplish this when using **ListView**? or do I need to create another function in my views.py?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You would need to create a form for that and render it in your template. You would capture its submission in your view and increment the vote counter. You can check how to handle forms within class-based views here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: `if person['id'] not in [i.id for i in persons]: Person.vote += 1  Person.save()` would be the fast way but you should add a user field to the model so you can identify the user properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your case, you can accomplish this fair simply by creating a function view that process the vote and redirects back the to list view.

something like:

```
def process_vote(request, person_id):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, id=person_id)
    person.vote = F('vote') + 1  # Using an F expression to avoid race conditions
    person.save()
    return redirect('list_view') # Redirect to anywhere
```

Then on your form, set the action param of the form to that view url

Comment: Hey Julio, thank you so much for your help. Now, just to clarify. I would need to create this function in my views.py correct? This is what I have in my urls.py https://gist.github.com/tp00012x/6d6e25d40bc61c09fbcf763c33169534 , are you saying that I should create a new url, so it redirects to that new url when I click on <input value="Yes!">? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey. You need to create an url for the view `process_vote` that accepts a person_id key argument on the url. It would be something like:
`url(r'^api/vote/(?P<person_id>[0-9]+)$', views.process_vote),`. Add that url to your form action and pass to it the person id.  The redirection is from the process_vote view to your PersonList view. So when an user clicks the button it sends the request. Process the vote and later it sends the user back to the list

Comment: Julio, I got it working thanks to you. Thank you again. Now, the only thing is that it reloads the page every time after I click. Do you know how I stop it from doing that so it just updates the number of votes and not the whole thing?

Comment: You will have to do this using ajax. I have seen that you are using DRF. Do a view similar to process_vote that process the vote but that does not respond with a redirection, instead of that just use a empty response. Now on the client side you have to request to that url using ajax, and change the vote count on the page using javascript